# can not download source code with intellij IDEA 2019.2 with maven3 on mac os

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea

I'm using IDEA2019.2, when I click Download Sources, the IDEA prompt "Sources not found for xxxx", but the cmd line "mvn depencency:source" works. the IDE and the cmd line use the same settings.xml and the same maven. I tried maven 3.3.9, 3.6.2, none of them works.

I tried the operation on my Windows notebook, with the same config files and maven, it works fine.

the idea log :

```
2019-10-12 19:52:18,763 [4822036]   INFO -      #org.jetbrains.idea.maven - org.eclipse.aether.resolution.ArtifactResolutionException: Could not find artifact commons-logging:commons-logging:jar:sources:1.2
java.lang.RuntimeException: org.eclipse.aether.resolution.ArtifactResolutionException: Could not find artifact commons-logging:commons-logging:jar:sources:1.2
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolve(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:444)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolveArtifacts(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:246)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolveArtifact(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:223)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultRepositorySystem.resolveArtifact(DefaultRepositorySystem.java:294)
    at org.jetbrains.idea.maven.server.Maven3XServerEmbedder.resolve(Maven3XServerEmbedder.java:1272)
    at org.jetbrains.idea.maven.server.Maven3XServerEmbedder.doResolve(Maven3XServerEmbedder.java:1221)
    at org.jetbrains.idea.maven.server.Maven3XServerEmbedder.doResolve(Maven3XServerEmbedder.java:1215)
    at org.jetbrains.idea.maven.server.Maven3XServerEmbedder.resolve(Maven3XServerEmbedder.java:1078)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor86.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:357)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:200)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:197)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Transport.java:196)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(TCPTransport.java:573)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(TCPTransport.java:834)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.lambda$run$0(TCPTransport.java:688)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(TCPTransport.java:687)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: org.eclipse.aether.transfer.ArtifactNotFoundException: Could not find artifact commons-logging:commons-logging:jar:sources:1.2
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolve(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:434)
    ... 23 more
```

Comment: I usually encounter this behaviour when using Nexus a repository proxy. But usually on windows. There are quite some related issues in the tracker: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/IDEA?q=maven%20download%20sources - maybe one contains some hints to workaround this. Are you using the embedded maven runner or an external maven installation?

Comment: @Swayangjit i tried the embedded maven and the installation both, none of them works

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you encountered the issue https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-196895

This is fixed in 2019.3 EAP